# Apache artemis need to created many connection as many server node with STRICT config

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have check [clustered-static-discovery](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery), also udp based clustering  ,
What i have seen if i have 2 nodes in cluster then must required 2 connection, if i have 4 then must required 4 connection to consume message round robinly .

Suppose i have 2 server the need 2 connection if i have created only one connection or listener, and will produce 10 message then i will missed 5 message.

How we can receive message in one connection instead of creating many connect(depends on how many server nodes are used).
Because there is a scenario when run time node added, so we will miss those message which will come to run time added node

here is example I have 2 nodes(with in cluster) and one connection

```
import javax.jms.*;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.ActiveMQJMSClient;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionInternal;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.util.ServerUtil;
/**
 * A simple example that demonstrates server side load-balancing of messages between the queue instances on different
 * nodes of the cluster. The cluster is created from a static list of nodes.
 */
public class StaticClusteredQueueExample {
   public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
      Connection connection0 = null;
      try {
         
         Topic topic = ActiveMQJMSClient.createTopic("exampleTopic");
        
         ConnectionFactory cf0 = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:9616");
         Thread.sleep(2000);
         
         connection0 = cf0.createConnection();
         final String clientID = "admin";
         connection0.setClientID(clientID);
         final String subscriptionName = "mySub";
      
         Session session0 = connection0.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         connection0.start();
         
         MessageConsumer subscriber0 = session0.createDurableSubscriber(topic, subscriptionName);
         Thread.sleep(2000);
         
         MessageProducer producer = session0.createProducer(topic);
         //  We send 20 messages to server 
         final int numMessages = 20;
         for (int i = 0; i < numMessages; i++) {
            TextMessage message = session0.createTextMessage("This is text message " + i);
            producer.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message: " + message.getText());
         }
         Thread.sleep(2000);
                  
         for (int i = 0; i < numMessages; i += 2) {
            try {
               TextMessage message0 = (TextMessage) subscriber0.receive(5000);
               System.out.println("" + message0.getText() + ": from node " + ServerUtil.getServer(connection0));
            } catch (Exception e) {}
         }
      } finally {
         // Step 15. Be sure to close our resources!
         if (connection0 != null) {
            connection0.close();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In above example send 20 message by producer
but when i am printing output it only print 10 message instead of 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the clustering documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/clusters.html) states, the way messages are load-balanced in the cluster depends on the `<message-load-balancing>` configuration element on `<cluster-connection>`.  The documentation states:

> This parameter determines if/how messages will be distributed between other nodes of the cluster. It can be one of three values - `OFF`, `STRICT`, or `ON_DEMAND` (default). This parameter replaces the deprecated `forward-when-no-consumers` parameter.
>
> If this is set to `OFF` then messages will never be forwarded to another node in the cluster
>
> If this is set to `STRICT` then each incoming message will be round robin'd even though the same queues on the other nodes of the cluster may have no consumers at all, or they may have consumers that have non matching message filters (selectors). Note that Apache ActiveMQ Artemis will not forward messages to other nodes if there are no queues of the same name on the other nodes, even if this parameter is set to `STRICT`. Using `STRICT` is like setting the legacy `forward-when-no-consumers` parameter to `true`.
>
> If this is set to `ON_DEMAND` then Apache ActiveMQ Artemis will only forward messages to other nodes of the cluster if the address to which they are being forwarded has queues which have consumers, and if those consumers have message filters (selectors) at least one of those selectors must match the message. Using `ON_DEMAND` is like setting the `legacy forward-when-no-consumers` parameter to `false`.
>
> Default is `ON_DEMAND`.

The `clustered-static-discovery` example uses `STRICT` for `<message-load-balancing>` which is why a connection to every node is required.

Also, keep in mind that `<redistribution-delay>` impacts behavior here.  You can read more about that in the "Message Redistribution" section in [the clustering documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/clusters.html).

If you use `ON_DEMAND` for `<message-load-balancing>` and a `<redistribution-delay>` that is `>=0` then you will be able to consume every message on a particular queue in the cluster from a connection to a single node.

Comment: load balancing is server side is working, and this is not issue, 
problem is when i am using STRICT means load will balance on server side     , suppose i have two node using STRICT in cluster,  then must need 2 connection in client side, does there is any solution, without changing STRICT in cluster i can consume message in using only one connection.

Comment: No.  There is no solution whereby you can consume every message on a particular queue in the cluster from a connection to a single node if message-load-balancing is configured as STRICT.  Message redistribution only happens if message-load-balancing is configured as ON_DEMAND as the documentation states.